# The institution where I got my degree is merging with another, how should I list it on my CV?

Tags: cv, degree

The university from which I obtained my undergraduate degree (A) has announced that it is planning to merge with another university in the area (B), to form a new university (C).

How should I list the institution on my CV after the merge is completed?
The answers in the related question [here](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/197779/program-where-i-earned-my-masters-is-changing-its-name-in-2023-2024-does-this) suggest that I should list the new name if the university changes name. I feel that this would be disingenuous however - it's not as simple as the university changing names because two separate institutions with rather different reputations are becoming a new one.

At the same time  I worry that if I simply keep the old name then it might be harder to find on (for example) university rankings sites, unless the person searching knew to look back in time.

Comment: I would do this: "University A (now University C)"

Comment: @peterh I feel as if that is concealing the fact that it has been created through a merge. An area of concern is that (for example) A has a reputation for being pretty average in certain areas, while B has quite a good reputation for those. If C ends up having a great reputation for that area, I wouldn't want anyone to think I was using the name of C to cover up the average reputation of where I actually did the study.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to refer to a university that changed its name?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/56313/how-to-refer-to-a-university-that-changed-its-name)

Comment: Call your old university (the bureau in it that deals with student records, transcripts, etc) and just ask them for advice.

Answer (score 2):

As peterh says in a comment, for a simple name change you would write "University A (now University C)". If you want to emphasise that it was a merger, not a simple name change, you could therefore write "University A (now part of University C)".